# Formazione di sostantivi derivati da verbi: uso dei suffissi

Tags: word-usage, suffix

Sostantivi che rappresentano la messa in atto di un'azione, e quindi di un verbo, sono ottenuti mediante l'aggiunta di un suffisso alla radice del verbo. I suffissi sono vari e abbiamo quindi, volendo isolarne delle classi:

> campionamento da *campionare* 
>      fortificazione da *fortificare* 
>      mietitura da *mietere*

Oltre ai suffissi -mento, -zione e -tura non ne trovo altri (aggiungetene se me ne sfuggono!), ma c'è una regola per l'utilizzo dell'uno o dell'altro? La coniugazione di appartenenza del verbo non sembra giocare un ruolo.

Sarebbe del tutto scorretto quindi dire, ad esempio, *campionatura*? L'accezione cambierebbe? Insomma, come si sceglie il suffisso in questi casi?

Comment: posso aggiungere che -aggio ha avuto molta fortuna tra il XVII e il XIX secolo, perché seguiva la formazione francese in -age, ma adesso è praticamente in disuso.

Comment: Potresti dare qualche esempio? Poi che significa che è in disuso? Ci son tante parole in -aggio.

Comment: "in disuso" significa che non è più produttivo, quindi *oggi* è difficile che si crei un nuovo lemma in -aggio: è l'equivalente del suffisso -oni per creare un avverbio da un sostantivo ("mettersi ginocchioni"). Un controesempio è "allunaggio", che però è costruito come "atterraggio". Altri esempi: "lavare &rarr; lavaggio (fr. lavage, attest. 1841)", "dosare &rarr; dosaggio (fr. dosage, attest. 1853)", "fissare &rarr; fissaggio (fr. fixage, attest. 1892 ma probabilmente precedente)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stai parlando dei suffissi nominali derivanti da verbi, e il signor Treccani ci viene ancora una volta in aiuto:

per -zione:

> "*Suffisso derivativo di nomi tratti da verbi. Se il verbo ha un part.
>   pass. in -t-, la forma del suffisso è -zione*" (formato-> formazione)  [[cit]](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sione-zione/)

per -mento:

> *Suffisso derivativo di nomi che indicano la nozione astratta dei verbi da cui sono tratti o designano l’effetto o il risultato
>   dell’azione da essi espressa.* [[cit]](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mento_res-0d07dd4f-0026-11de-9d89-0016357eee51/)

per -tura non sono riuscito a trovare informazioni sulla Treccani, ma wikipedia dice:

> *"deverbale astratto o concreto: indica l'atto espresso dal verbo"*[[cit]](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffissi_della_lingua_italiana)

Ce ne sono altri, ad esempio -aggio (lavaggio), -ata (camminata), -tore (lavoratore), che sono [listati qui](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffissi_della_lingua_italiana).

Insomma la situazione è varia, e per la maggior parte dei suffissi nominali si trovano le regole sulla [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/) (che più la consulto più mi stupisce).

**In particolare riguardo all'uso differente dei tre suffissi da te indicati** c'è [questo articolo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/nomi-di-azione_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/) (guarda caso sulla Treccani) che riporta quanto segue:

> In generale i tre suffissi -zione, -mento, -tura sono in distribuzione
>   complementare, vale a dire che ciascun verbo o classe di verbi
>   seleziona un solo suffisso. Ad es., -zione si aggiunge a verbi formati
>   col suffisso -izzare e -ificare, mentre non altrettanto bene si
>   aggiunge ai verbi formati col suffisso -eggiare, che invece
>   selezionano -mento

In particolare per il suffisso -mento c'è un fatto interessante:

> Lo stesso suffisso -mento, molto produttivo in italiano, è l’unico ad
>   aggiungersi ai verbi parasintetici per formare nomi d’azione
>   (ex: vecchio → invecchiamento)

**In conclusione**
Possiamo delineare le seguenti regole per i tre suffissi

1. sono complementari,
2. verbi con -izzare e -ificare prendono -zione come suffisso,
3. i verbi parasintetici prendono -mento
4. verbi formati col suffisso -eggiare prendono -mento

Comment: Non mi è del tutto chiara la differenza proprio tra i tre che ho listato: -mento rispetto a -zione nel caso di "campionare", darebbe un risultato diverso? Il verbo ha part. pass. in -t e quindi potrebbe andare in "campionazione", ma non si dice.

Comment: ho updatato la domanda ora risponde un po' meglio.

Comment: Bene, nell'articolo si dice anche che due sostantivi di uso diverso possono nascere dallo stesso verbo con suffissi diversi.

Comment: Si esatto, per tornare al tuo esempio, si ha sia _campionatura_ che _campionamento_ usati in due ambiti diversi.

Comment: `listati qui`... guarda che *listare* ha un [altro significato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tag/listare/) che non ha nulla a che vedere con *elencare*. È un po' come usare "scannare" al posto di "scandire"... (con riferimento al verbo inglese `to scan`)

Comment: @Bakuriu Anglicismi che prendono la forma italiana, anche io ne faccio uso, ma grazie per la notazione!

Comment: @Bakuriu purtroppo chi usa il computer in maniera intensiva (come immagino faccia martina, dato il lavoro che dichiara di fare nel [suo profilo](http://italian.stackexchange.com/users/22/martina)) spesso italianizza termini inglesi... mutandone un poco il significato... conseguenze della globalizzazione :)

Comment: @Bakuriu: sulla carta ti do anche ragione... ma sinceramente resterei perplesso sentendo qualcuno dire che vuole *scandire* un documento. Certo, meglio *scandire* che *scannare*, ma personalmente *scannerizzare*, o *passare allo scanner*, o ancora *scansionare* mi sembrano opzioni molto migliori.

Comment: @nico Io facevo riferimento ad un uso tecnico come "to scan an array ...", che non ha *nulla* a che vedere con la periferica "scanner".

Comment: @Bakuriu: ah, OK, non era chiaro dal commento precedente. In ogni caso quello lo tradurrei come *fare uno scan di un array* oppure *leggere [gli elementi di] un array*. Sinceramente *scandire* lo userei piuttosto in situazioni tipo: *non si capisce nulla quando parli, scandisci bene le parole!*.