# Sull'uso di "insomma"

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Quando ho scritto [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/12668) (prima di tutti gli aggiornamenti), ho usato l'avverbio "insomma" nell'ultima frase. Mi si è suggerito, però, che non si trattasse di una scelta adeguata perché i lettori potrebbero percepirlo come un'esortazione troppo forte. Infatti, il post è stato aggiornato senza questo "insomma" (nessun problema: va benissimo così).

Pongo questa domanda per cercare di comprendere perché è così.

Capisco che "insomma" ha l'uso seguente, che è quello che sarebbe avvertito dall'interlocutore come irritante (dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/insomma)):

> È anche esclamazione d’impazienza per troncare un’esitazione, per affrettare una decisione, per rafforzare la ripetizione di un invito già fatto precedentemente a rispondere, ad agire, a cessare da un’azione molesta, ecc.: *i., qui bisogna risolversi!; deciditi i., sì o no?; i., la volete smettere?; i., che cos’è tutto questo baccano?* Usato da solo, esprime per lo più irritazione o minaccia contenuta: *insomma!*

Tuttavia, sempre secondo il Treccani, "insomma" ha anche questo significato, che è quello a cui avevo cercato di riferirmi io (e sono sicura di aver adoperato "insomma" in questo modo nel passato; per esempio, nei pochi mesi in cui sono andata a lezione d'italiano):

> Espressione di uso molto com. (equivalente in genere a «in breve; in conclusione; riassumendo il già detto» e sim.), con cui si conclude un ragionamento, si riassume un’esposizione analitica, si introduce un giudizio riassuntivo e globale, si tronca e si rimette a fuoco la discussione di un argomento che minacciava di divagare e di andare per le lunghe, e sim.: *In somma sappi che tutti fur cherci E litterati grandi e di gran fama* (Dante); *in somma, figliol caro, io non ci ho colpa* (Manzoni); *il libro è scritto male, è pieno di contraddizioni, è povero di pensiero: i., non vale proprio la pena di leggerlo; i., per non dilungarci, la questione essenziale è questa; i., si può sapere che cosa t’ha detto?; i., io spero che ci siamo capiti*.

Dunque, la mia domanda è: perché l'"insomma" che avevo usato nel mio post non verrebbe percepito in questo ultimo modo?

Per rendere la questione un po' più semplice, ecco altre domande poste su questo sito in passato in cui si usa "insomma" alla fine del post: [[1]](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1410/), [[2]](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/9540/), [[3]](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5593/)  e [[4]](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/10732/).

La domanda sarebbe: esistono differenze tra l'uso di "insomma" che si fa in questi post e quello che avevo fatto io? Quali sono queste differenze?

Comment: La mia impressione è che il significato di “in definitiva” sia stato perso e che “insomma” sia ormai più “esortativo”, con una sfumatura più di ordine che di semplice esortazione.

Comment: La mia impressione è diversa da quella di egreg, e ho anche usato la parola per ribadire/tagliar corto in un recente post su questo sito ("Se invece c'è la volontà d'ingarbugliare, insomma lo si fa apposta, ...").

Answer (score -1):

"Insomma" è un cosiddetto "marker discorsivo" che ha due funzioni, come hai scritto sopra: una di esortazione perentoria, l'altra riassuntiva o conclusiva riguardo tema della conversazione a mo' di "per farla breve". Per identificare la funzione il contesto è fondamentale. "Insomma volete spiegarmi" o simili fa propendere per la prima lettura (implica che fino a quel momento l'interlocutore ha tergiversato). So bene che tu non intendevi ciò. Te l'ho sotto fatto notare perché sei interessanta alle sfumature dell'italiano. Se si osservano gli esempi che riporti per la seconda funzione, noti che in alcuni casi il verbo è determinante. "Insomma sappi" non è un imperativo vero e proprio, ma significa "ti informo che". In altri, "insomma" si riferisce a chi enuncia: " in somma, figliol caro, io non ci ho colpa" e quindi non coinvolge l'interlocutore. "Insomma si può sapere cosa t'ha detto?", invece, rispecchia la prima e non la seconda funzione. PS: il downvote non te l'ho dato io visto che trovo la domanda interessante.

Comment: Scusa, @Nico, ma non riesco a capire perché questo "insomma" implicherebbe che che fino a quel momento l'interlocutore abbia tergiversato quanto ho scritto precedentemente. E non si può dire "segnale discorsivo"?

Comment: @Charo In italiano si usano i termini "marker discorsivi", "segnali discorsivi" o "marcatori discorsivi". Non fa differenza. Non ho capito quello che non hai capito.

Comment: Cosa non ho capito? La tua risposta credo affermi che, se si scrive "Insomma, sapreste spiegarmi..." o qualcosa di simile, chi scrive questo assume che il lettore abbia tergiversato riguardo a quanto detto prima, ma non riesco a capire perché dovrebbe essere così. Veramente mi sembra molto strano: come può sapere chi scrive se i lettori tergiverseranno?

Comment: @charo "tergiversare" vuol dire perdere tempo senza arrivare al dunque... Questa è l'implicazione che io associo alla frase in quel contesto. Non ho scritto che tu l'abbia intesa.

Comment: Non ho detto che io l'avesse intesa così, ma che la tua risposta dice che scrivere "insomma..." implica questo e che io non riesco a capire perché.

Comment: Mi pare di averlo spiegato anche in base ai due usi riportati dai dizionari. se non ci sono riuscito, ci sarà sicuramente qualcuno che saprà farlo meglio di me.

Comment: @Charo: "come può sapere chi scrive se i lettori tergiverseranno?". Non lo può sapere se non è un veggente, ma lo può supporre, che è anche più offensivo. Le parole sono lo specchio del pensiero, quando non sono ben ponderate (e quindi in qualche modo false o distorte). Nico ha spiegato benissimo due usi del termine, e ha *perfettamente* ragione (e ribadisco *perfettamente*, è inutile che tu ne discuta) ...

Comment: Il mio commento non è per dire che tu hai offeso, non padroneggi completamente la nostra lingua e credi che sui libri trovi tutte le infinite sfumature. Non è così, almeno sulle sfumature fidati di chi, dell'Italiano, ne sa più di te.